# Tableau: Displaying Averages and Aggregate Calculations In Filtered Visualizations

Tags: visualization, graphs, tableau

I'm new to Tableau and I just started by making a graph with multiple filters. What I want to do is display some averages of some columns and other aggregate functions dynamically as the filters are changed by the viewer.

Here is the [viz](https://public.tableau.com/profile/himanish.ganjoo#!/vizhome/MSDInChases/Sheet2?publish=yes).

Now, as someone changes the filters, I want to display an average of the  column, and let's say, a weighted average of the "Runs" column with "Strike Rate" as the weight, and so on. This should update live, as the filters are changed, and should be based on the currently selected values.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks a ton!